# Binding datatable values into a checkbox that's placed inside GridView

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datatable

I am binding a datatable to a GridView which has a checkbox in one of its fields. I have trouble getting the checkbox to be checked according to the datatable.

This is what I have thus far:

```
 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Approved" SortExpression="Approved">
      <ItemTemplate>
      <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Approved").ToString() == "Y" ? true : false %>'
                                 Enabled="false" />
      </ItemTemplate>
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

Code Behind:

```
Dim adp As SqlDataAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd)
Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
adp.Fill(ds, "table_name")
dt = New DataTable()
dt = ds.Tables("table_name")
GridView1.DataSource = dt
GridView1.DataBind()
```

Edit: Getting an error BC30201: Expression expected. on  this particular line:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%#Eval("Approved").ToString() == "Y" ? true : false %>'
                             Enabled="false" />
```

**Edit with ANSWER:** I finally got it to work, I found out that ternary operators does not exist in VB.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Approved").ToString().ToUpper().Trim() = "Y" %>' Enabled="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You code is right you may not be getting check boxes to be checked because some values may be saved with a space at beginning or at end so you need to use `Trim()` method also just to make sure that your condition satisfies call `ToUpper()` to convert database value to upper case so it matches with upper case `Y`.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" Checked='<%# Eval("Approved").ToString().ToUpper().Trim() == "Y" ? true : false %>'
                             Enabled="false" />
```

Comment: Getting an error on that line of code, BC30201: Expression expected.